# How can i make redirection to another page in cron jobs?

Tags: php, cron

I need solution for redirection to another page by `cron` job

Flow is like below:

=> There is one `cron` job which runs specific time and fetch data from table as per condition

=> Then I have to redirect to some other page attaching fetched data in url like below

http://www.test.com?seo_url=xxxx

so I tried redirection by PHP header but its not redirecting from `cron` jobs and as we know `cron` cant execute JS code so I cannot redirect from JS

So is there any solution for redirecting from `cron` job??

Comment: who should be redirected by cron job?

Comment: Redirection only occurs on browsers while cron scripts does not execute on browsers, so as ElefantPhace mentioned: you should use a curl request

Comment: I have to redirect it to php page , i am doing paypal cancellation from this, I have one page for paypal cancellation so i have to redirect on that page

Comment: @YaminLawar If you can share your exact workflow of how you are using this to do what (explain in detail how this is used to cancel ehich paypal orders and when) we will certainly try to help you out through an alternative method.

Comment: Thanks to all it solved by curl thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplest curl call for your case would be as follows:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = 'www.test.com?seo_url=xxxx';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```